# BeautifulSoup find specific string

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just started a little 'project' to learn beautiful soup and even though BS website is massive I couldn't find answer to my question. 
I'm analysing Billboard100 and managed to get a list of all songs by their divs as an array - nice, I can call separate list for different songs. The problem starts when I need to get few details - name of song, name of artist etc from that list. I tried text.strip() and then split() and indexing but different songs have different details in different positions, which means I should probably find them by div classes as they use the same ones for all songs and that's where I get stuck.

```
<div class="chart-list-item__title">
<span class="chart-list-item__title-text">
Mona Lisa
</span>
</div>
<div class="chart-list-item__artist">
 Lil Wayne Featuring Kendrick Lamar
</div>
```

That's just a bit of the code - let's say I'm trying to get 'Mona Lisa' and 'Lil Wayne Featuring Kendrick Lamar'. Is there a way of using BeautifulSoup on HTML that I already extracted from the original HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the div with the desired class name:

This code assumes that you have just the card (the list item for your desired song) as your soup, not the whole page:

```
title = card.find("div", {"class": "chart-list-item__title"}).contents[0]
artist = card.find("div", {"class": "chart-list-item__artist"}).contents[0]
```